# Content Builder Approvals Platform Question

Tags: approval-process, content-builder

1. Is there a way to enable email notification of when new comments are posted in the approvals platform? Currently, I only receive email notification when new content is submitted.
2. Is there a way to tag team members in comments? This way they can receive notifications about content areas that apply specifically to them.